# A pearl that moves in a smooth vertical hoop (Circular motion)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, kinematics

I couldn't understand something about the situation of a pearl that moves in a smooth vertical hoop in circular motion.
When the normal force equals 0 , the pearl didn't disconnect from the smooth vertical hoop, even though the pearl had velocity at that point.
Why the pearl didn't disconnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had a ***tangential*** velocity and its weight was enough to provide the centripetal force for motion.